# How to draw multiple curved arrows pointing to the same node in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, arrows

How do I draw a node with multiple curved arrows pointing back to it, optionally paired with some text as in illustration?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! There are *many* ways of drawing these things. One way is just to look up `loop` in section 70.4 of the pgfmanual. Another way is

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,fill] (X){};
\draw[-latex,postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
mark=at position 0.4 with {\node[anchor=west]{text 1};}}}] (X) to[out=50,in=65-90] ++ (65:2) to[out=65+90,in=80] (X);
\draw[-latex,postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
mark=at position 0.65 with {\node[anchor=west]{text 2};}}}] 
(X) to[out=-105,in=180] ++ (-90:2) to[out=0,in=-75] (X);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It really depends on what precisely you want. You can define styles to simplify your life, of course.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! How do I add text next to the arcs?

Comment: You're probably confusing me with somebody else. But many thanks ^_^